# WinForms Richtextbox: predefined Tabsize changes when pasting RTF formated text

Tags: winforms, powershell, rtf

I've got a `RichTextBox` in my `Poshscript`. I defined the tab sizes via

```
$RichTextBox.SelectionTabs = (10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
```

This works as expected.
**But** when i paste an RTF-formated text into the `RichTextBox` via

```
$RichTextBox.SelectedRtf = $myRTFtext
```

these predefined tab sizes were ignored and a much larger tab sizes was placed.
How can i change/prevent that?

I've tried setting the `selectionTabs`-property again, directly before and/or after the paste, without any effect. 
I also tried setting the `tabSize` **inside** the rtf text with `deftab100`, also no effect (if i have done it right).

Any ideas? 
Thanks and best regards, 
rob

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0247f1fd-2f89-4a81-a707-744e17152530/richtextbox-tab-setting last post